# characterai.errors.ServerError: create_chat already exists

Tags: python

I am trying to use the unofficial Character.ai API.
Here's the Docs and official library:
https://pycai.gitbook.io/welcome/
https://pypi.org/project/characterai/

I keep getting error:

```
  File "C:\Users\expo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\characterai\pyasynccai.py", line 718, in new_chat
    raise errors.ServerError(response['comment'])
characterai.errors.ServerError: create_chat already exists
```

My code is this:

```py
if message.content == ',reset':
        try:
            chat = await client.chat2.get_chat(char)
            authordict = await client.user.info()
            author = str(authordict['user']['user']['id'])
            chat_id = chat['chats'][0]['chat_id']
            async with client.connect() as chat2:
                try:
                    response, answer = await chat2.new_chat(
                        char, chat_id, author, with_greeting=False
                    )
                except Exception as e:
                    await message.reply(e)

            await message.reply('<:check:1198462410139390062> || || **Chat restarted!**')
            return None
        except Exception as e:
            await message.reply(e)
```

I tried to use my code to reset the chat but unfortunately I keep getting an error, which I don't know why. According to the docs my code should work perfectly.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)